# How do I output "dumb" apostrophes with the sffms package?

Tags: macros, font-encodings

I'm using the [sffms](http://www.mcdemarco.net/sffms/) package to typeset a book manuscript (using the version of the package shipped with TexLive 2013 on a Mac). I want to output both double and single quotes so they are "dumb" or straight quotes, rather than the typographic quotes normally output by LaTeX. sffms has a "dumb" option to output straight quotes, but it only affects double quotes, not single quotes.

I found a [suggestion](http://ansuz.sooke.bc.ca/software/latex-tricks.php) on how to get sffms to also output straight single quotes, by adding this to the preamble of my document:

```
\def\rquote{{\fontencoding{TS1}\selectfont\char39}}
\def\lquote{{\fontencoding{TS1}\selectfont\char39}}
```

As far as I can tell, this overrides an `rquote` and `lquote` macro that is defined in the file `sffdumb.sty` file that is part of the sffms package.

However, it did not work for me. `pdflatex` output the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `TS1' unknown.
```

Is there a way to get straight single quotes with the sffms package?

---

I added `\usepackage{textcomp}` to the preamble, which does the job, but this error was generated when building the PDF:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\actrq ->\futurelet \next 
                          \rqtest 
l.54 ...See the documentation for details\@gobble}
```

Comment: Add `\usepackage{textcomp}`.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks! That sort of worked, but generated a new error—I updated my question to note that.

Answer (score 2):

Redefine in a more sensible way the active characters:

```
\documentclass[dumb]{sffms}

% undefine the single quotes
\let'\relax \let`\relax

\usepackage{textcomp}

% redefine them in a more sensible way
\makeatletter
\protected\def`{\@ifnextchar`{"\@gobble}\textquotesingle}
\protected\def'{\@ifnextchar'{"\@gobble}\textquotesingle}
\makeatother

\author{B C}
\title{A}

\begin{document}

"dumb" 'dumb' ``dumb'' `dumb'

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[courier]{sffms}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\author{H. G. Wells}
\surname{Wells}
\address{47 The High Street\\ Bromley, Kent}
\title{The Country of the Blind}
\runningtitle{Blind}
\disposable
\def\rquote{{\fontencoding{TS1}\selectfont\char39}}
\def\lquote{{\fontencoding{TS1}\selectfont\char39}}
\begin{document}

foo \lquote bar\rquote\ 'baz'

\end{document}
```

[image]

or without the option `[courier]`:

[image]